Probability related to "Gaussian ball"
For some reason, I need to calculate (estimate, especially finding an upper bound of) the probability of this event:
$$E_1 \triangleq \{ \|u+\sqrt{a}Z \|_2 \geq v \},$$
where $u \in \mathbb{R}^m$ is some known point in $\mathbb{R}^m$. And both $a,v\in \mathbb{R}_{++}$ are known real numbers nonnegative. And $Z\sim N(0,1)^{\otimes m}$, this means $Z$ is a dimension $m$ real random vector whose each entry are iid drawn following a standard Gaussian distribution.
For a related event (the negation of $E_1$): $$\neg E_1 =  \{ \|u+\sqrt{a}Z \|_2 < v \},$$
one can use Chernoff bound to obtain an upper bound. In detail, it is:
$$P(\neg E_1)\leq \inf_{\gamma <0} e^{-\gamma v^2} \mathbb{E}[e^{\gamma \|u+\sqrt{a}Z \|^2}],$$ and one can invoke the equality
$$\mathbb{E}[e^{\gamma \|u+\sqrt{a}Z \|^2}] = (1-2a\gamma)^{-m/2} \exp{\frac{\gamma \|u\|_2}{1-2a\gamma}}, \forall \gamma < 0$$
to get a decent bound. (This procedure is used in equation (12) in this paper)
I want to know whether there is a method to upper bound $P(E_1)$ as well?

If it helps, note by the rotational symmetry of $Z$ that one can assume $u=(t,0,\dots,0)$ for some $t\ge0$.
